# How to get response string from NSURLSessionTask

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetwork 3.0 for HTTP get request.
I am even getting response. But i want to take response data as `NSString`. 
Can someone please help me how to get response data as `NSString`

Here is my code,

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *operation = [AFHTTPSessionManager alloc];

    [operation GET:controlURL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


        NSLog(@"success: %@", responseObject);

        NSString *xmlString = [responseObject ];// i am facing problem here
```

Comment: what `NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);` this statement prints?

Comment: please print the responseObject then what is the value you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want response data in your string then try this:

```
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
```